# Identify and disable specific extensions that are causing Nautilus to hang

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

Occasionally nautilus tends to hang until killed.
This has to do with some extension.

How can I

- find out which extension is blocking nautilus?
- disable nautilus extensions separately?

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
my load stays constant.

Comment: Open a terminal session, launch Nautilus by there and watch it's output, if you can see some error message related to this hanging

Comment: sadly it isn't always clear when this happens and also even when i have done that it did not display relevant information. only gtk faults when starting nautilus  .   (assume that i am no noob)

Comment: There is only 1 extension installed by default, nautilus-sendto. There is nautilus integration by default in deja-dup, gnome-terminal, file-roller & maybe totem-plugins. So it's unlikely your issue is as described unless you've installed some extensions yourself. If so, remove them..

Comment: actually they come as a package, and i dont want to remove them for general users but only disable them .. for ME.  that is why i ask "disable" extension. dont make an x instead of y ANSWER it is neither clever nor correct

Comment: what about /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-tracker-tags.so